# How to sent a website url as link to multiple Facebook Friends?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am setting up a website. I want users to invite Facebook friends to look at the page the users can make on my website. So i'm trying to get it done. But i think the FB Api is not set up to do what i want to do. I think it is to prevent from spamming, but i really like to know if it can be done or not.

This is what i have so far. Users can login with FB and i present a decent list of FB friends.
Each friend has a checkbox. When a user submits the form, i collect all the checked friends id's:

```
var sendUIDs = '';
var mfsForm = document.getElementById('mfsForm');
for (var i = 0; i < mfsForm.friends.length; i++) {
    if (mfsForm.friends[i].checked) {
        sendUIDs += mfsForm.friends[i].value + ',';
    }
}
```

While i was trying, i came up with this "sollution" for sending all the friends the same invite:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    to: sendUIDs,
    message: "Hey come on look at my site",
    data:  "mywebsite.com/userlink"
});
```

Looking great I thought. Exactly what i wanted... i thought.

Unfortunately this is only used for games? First of all i could not find the invite. It was there, but it seems to disappear. Then i found out it was in the App/Games/Activity tab.

I managed to get the notification in the "notification" tab by adding a Canvas to my FB App. Almost there i thought. Well, not exactly... I want the friends to visit my page by the given data link and not some weird ?number.

So i gave up this path and tried the other way and came up with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mfsForm.friends.length; i++) {
    if (mfsForm.friends[i].checked) {
        var uid = mfsForm.friends[i].value;
        FB.ui({
            to : uid,
            method: 'send',
            name: 'Visit my page',
            link: 'mywebsite.com/userlink'
        });
    }
}
```

This works more or less, but produces a popup for every friend with an empty message box. Not very friendly and, well... stupid :)

I also tried the former setup, but instead of "apprequests" i used this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to: sendUIDs,
    message: "Hey come on look at my site",
    data:  "mywebsite.com/userlink"
});
```

where i tried this for the sendUIDs: [1, 2, ...] and just 1, 2, ...

No luck, because FB only processed one name.

I would think there must be a way to get the job done, but for now i am very confused how to proceed. I would think FB could make things a bit more easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Send and Share Dialogs are built for this (sharing a Website URL on a wall or send it to friends in a PM), just let him choose the friends in the popup. That way, you don´t even need to authorize the user, and you can´t get ALL friends anyway (only those who authorized the app too).

About the message parameter: You are not allowed to prefill the message, it has to be 100% user generated. See the Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

> 2.3 Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments,
>   and captions.

The FB.ui Dialogs ignore the message parameter anyway.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that my way, with a neat selection list of all my friends is a "no-go" and i only can use the popup to let the users fill in their friends?

Comment: that is correct. that selection will not work in your case, and the dialog offers all the functionality you need anyway, without the need to program anything.